# Custom shape does not appear in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, view, parent, android-relativelayout

I have the following problem with my application: I have created a custom View Class:

```
 private class MyCustomPanel extends View {
        private int width;
        private int height;
        public MyCustomPanel(Context context,int width,int height) 
        {
            super(context);
            this.height=height;
            this.width=width;

        }
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

            Paint paint  = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pending));

            float radius=(height)/2;
            float center_x = (width)/2;
            float center_y = (height)/2;

            Log.d("DEBUG","R="+radius+" cx="+center_x+" cy="+center_y);

            final RectF oval = new RectF();
            oval.set(center_x- radius, 

                    center_y - radius, 

                    center_x + radius, 

                    center_y + radius);

            //Draw a left semicircle
            canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, 180, false, paint);
        }
    }
```

This class is an inner class and I am trying to add in it a `RelativeLayout` in front of a Button.
I have successfully tried to add it to another layout, so it is added and drawn correctly (see here [screenshot](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/4912/screenshot20130321at410.png)).

In the previous case the draw function is called and the semicircle is drawn.

**In the following though the draw function is not called**..
I use this code:

```
ViewGroup p=(ViewGroup)button.getParent();
MyCustomPanel c=new MyCustomPanel(p.getContext(),p.getWidth(),p.getHeight());
((ViewGroup)p.findViewById(R.id.semicircleFrame)).addView(c);
```

and the XML in of the RelatedLayout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
android:id="@+id/frame">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</Button>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/semicircleFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

</RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The hierarchy viewer shows the following:
[screenshot](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/7769/screenshot20130321at435.png)

I have also try to add it directly to the parent `frame` but the same.

Please Help me

Comment: Have you checked that `p.getWidth()` and `p.getHeight()` return values greater than zero? If you call those methods before the first measure/layout pass, they will return zero. HierarchyViewer should show you what the measured/actual width and height is of your custom panel.

Comment: To clarify what @Karakuri said, you should correctly implement `onMeasure()`, see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom).

Comment: I tryed inserting manually values (smaller Width and Length than the contener view) and nothing happens.
If you notice I am using `Log.d("DEBUG","R="+radius+" cx="+center_x+" cy="+center_y);` in order to see whether the draw function is called. But in the problematic case this line is never reached!!

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with a view in Relative layout thatwas dependent on the Relative layout's size.
I solved this problem problematically by updating the inner view size

```
private void updateViewSize()
if(rootContainer == null || rootContainer.getLayoutParams() == null)
return;
rootContainer.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ScalingUtil.getScreenSize().getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams oldLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.deals_card_center_bg).getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(rootContainer.getMeasuredWidth(), rootContainer.getMeasuredHeight());
    layoutParams.setMargins(oldLayoutParams.leftMargin, oldLayoutParams.topMargin, oldLayoutParams.rightMargin, oldLayoutParams.bottomMargin);

    rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.deals_card_center_bg).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```